# How do I scale an SVG polygon in ems?

Tags: html, svg

I'm embedding an `<svg>` element directly in an HTML5 document, and I want to scale a repeating background pattern in terms of the page's font size.  No problem, SVG supports CSS units, so I can just specify the size in ems, right?

The SVG spec [claims](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units) "All [coordinates](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeCoordinate) and [lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeLength) in SVG can be specified with or without a unit identifier."  And, indeed, both of these do exactly what I was hoping for:

```
<rect x='1em' y='2em' width='3em' height='4em' />
<circle cx='6em' cy='7em' r='8em' />
```

But polygons (for example) have their own [completely different definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#PointsBNF) of the word "coordinate," such that this raises an error instead of drawing a 1 em triangle:

```
<polygon points='0 0, 0 1em, 1em 0' />
```

[Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) are the same way -- understandably, since they're already using the letters for a different purpose.

And [transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) such as "scale" expect a "number," not a "coordinate" or "length", so this isn't allowed either (my browser seems to silently ignore the "transform" attribute):

```
<polygon points='0 0, 0 1, 1 0' transform='scale(1em)' />
```

So I guess I can't even figure out how to draw a 1 em triangle, much less anything more complicated.  Am I overlooking a reasonable way of doing it?  What about an unreasonable way?  Should I give up and use a `<canvas>` element instead, or would that be even worse?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can wrap your polygons in an inner `<svg>` element to scale them as you wish. The viewBox controls the coordinate system of the objects it contains and the height and width attributes control how big it looks.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" height="1em" width="1em" y="7em">
      <polygon points='0 0, 0 1, 1 0' />
  </svg>
  <circle cx='6em' cy='7em' r='2em' />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply transforms to any item and use em or any other units.

For example, this works just fine:

```
<polygon points='0 0, 0 1, 1 0' transform='scale(2em 1.5em)' />
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in Edge version 87.0.664.75