# SVG polygon points with percentage units support

Tags: svg

I am trying to have a fluid SVG canvas that can resize easily. So far I'm using percentages everywhere. However it seems like SVG `polygon` and `path`s do not support percentages in `point` attribute. Here's an example:

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/yRbNH/)

```
<svg width='90%' height='90%' style='background-color: whitesmoke'>
    <rect x='40%' y='40%' width='25%' height='25%' />

    <polygon points="0,0 0,100 30,20 30,0" />
    <polygon points="30,0 30,20 60,0 60,0" />
    <polygon points="60,0 60,0 90,30 90,0" />
</svg>
```

However if I start to change numbers in `points` attribute to percentages it fails with parsing error in console. I am looking for a way to have the polygon that can resize with the `<svg>` element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scale an SVG polygon in ems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515524/how-do-i-scale-an-svg-polygon-in-ems)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

By using viewBox and a container element (of whatever size) I think you can achieve the effect you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/davegaeddert/WpeH4/

```
<div id="svg-container" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style='background-color: whitesmoke'>
        <rect x='40%' y='40%' width='25%' height='25%' />

        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 30,20 30,0" />
        <polygon points="30,0 30,20 60,0 60,0" />
        <polygon points="60,0 60,0 90,30 90,0" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

If you give the viewBox a size of `0 0 100 100` then the points can be written like percentages and the shape will scale with the svg.

Comment: @FlorianB - The attribute vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" should resolve that.

Comment: Great, but it keeps it as a sqare right? 
Is there a solution when you want to have it full screen (most of the time with an horizontal ratio)?

Comment: @alan_langlois I don't think this limits it to a square -- try changing the width and height of #svg-container in the jsfiddle example (i.e. `#svg-container { width: 400px; height: 100px; }`)...

Comment: This worked very well for me, being able to responsively shrink an existing SVG. Thanks! Although, one thing to note was that in order to properly maintain the svg sizing I had to use `display:block;` on the `svg` element.

Comment: Can `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` be applied to a `<g>` tag or some other parent? I couldn't get it to work without applying it directly to the `<path>`, and having a lot of paths, this could be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the elements together with `g` and use a transform:

```
<svg width='90%' height='90%' style='background-color: whitesmoke'>
    <rect x='40%' y='40%' width='25%' height='25%' />

    <g transform="scale(0.4 0.4)">
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 30,20 30,0"/>
        <polygon points="30,0 30,20 60,0 60,0"/>
        <polygon points="60,0 60,0 90,30 90,0"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That doesn't help. At the end, you scaled a 90px-wide polygon group to 45px fixed number. What I need is, something resizes with the `svg` element. Right now `rect` does so, it does have nothing fixed. Assume I got a triangle with `polygon`, how am I gonna behave it the same way? Try making `<svg width="10%" height="10%">` you'll get what I mean.

Comment: Can't you use a `viewBox` then? It scales everything automatically.

Comment: OK `viewBox` kinda does it, I now hit something seems like `d3.js` bug. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if you are using a percentage in your viewBox or not. I ran across this question after fixing up my viewBox. Here is a link to what I found out if it is causing the d3.js error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287355/d3js-svg-viewbox-attribute