# D3JS SVG Viewbox Attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am appending an svg to my div and applying a viewBox attribute of '0 0 100% 100%'. My console is stating an error from d3.js.

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute viewBox="0 0 100% 100%"
```

Here is snippet from the code

```
d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 100% 100%");
```

Is using percentages in a viewBox attribute allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[a valid viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) must consist of 4 numbers separated by whitespace and/or comma. Percentages are not allowed.

Comment: Your file should be displayed as if there was no viewBox attribute. Is that not the case?