# Using CSS and HTML5 to create navigation buttons using trapezoids

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-shapes

I'm trying to make a navigation-div with 4 buttons, one to go left, one to go right, another one to go down and yet another one to go up. Plus there needs to be an OK-button in the middle.

The buttons need to be positions that they form any (the size is not set) rectangle, inside the buttons are positions on the very right, left, top and bottom, and each of them are trapezoids, leaving a square in the middle for the OK-Button.

Just like that:
[image: Navbar Element]

What I've done is, that I created a trapezoid parent, with position relative shape using css:

```
.trapezoid_parent {
    position: relative;
}
```

And a trapezoid to use, which is absolute.

```
.trapezoid {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #f98d12;
    border-left: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid transparent;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 0; 
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

to make the top one, I flip the normal one and position it at the top:

```
.trapezoid.top {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    top: 0;
}
```

the bottom trapezoid just has to be position on the bottom:

```
.trapezoid.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Next up we need the left button

```
.left_button {
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 40%; 
    left:0; 
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

the one one the right

```
.right_button {
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 40%; 
    right:0; 
    z-index: 1;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

and last but not least the one in the center:

```
.center_button {
    height: 100%; position: absolute; width: 100%; right:0; z-index: 0;
}
```

Then, to put it all together I used the following html:

```
<div class="trapezoid_parent" style="width:200px; height:125px">
        <button class="left_button function"><i class='fa fa-arrow-left'></i></button>
        <button class="trapezoid top function"><i class='fa fa-arrow-down'></i></button>
        <button class="trapezoid bottom function"><i class='fa fa-arrow-down'></i></button>
        <button class="right_button function"><i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i></button>
        <button class="center_button">OK</button>
</div>
```

To make the whole thing responsive I made jQuery plugin which changes the sizes accordingly. It does that, by changing the border-bottom, border-left and border-right properties according to the size of the parent:

```
var internal_square_size = ((1.0 / 2) - plugin.settings.square_size);

var tpw = $element.width();
var tph = $element.height();
$(".trapezoid", $element)
.css("border-left-width", "" + (tpw * internal_square_size) + "px")
.css("border-right-width", "" + (tpw * internal_square_size) + "px")
.css("border-bottom-width","" + (tph * internal_square_size) + "px");

$(".left_button, .right_button", $element).css("width", "" + internal_square_size*100 + "%");
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Result]

You can view the whole thing here: [full jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/upzu36ay/)

There are still a few problems and I've spend all my magic already, but maybe someone else has a few ideas how to get the last few pieces.

The diagonal borders can not be displayed using the method presented, which is something I cannot live with. Has anyone an idea?

Second of all: It would be very nice, if the buttons could actually end with the diagonal, because touching a button which is to small is always tough. Am I missing something? Is HTML5 not equipped to do the thing I ask of it?

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought about that too, but I have never used svg before, could you line out how I would go about doing that as an answer?

Comment: That would be very broad and too long to go into here I think but I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I think I would be using an SVG here.

A brief example of the proposed structure.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  stroke: #006600;
}
#buttons polygon:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
#buttons rect:hover {
  fill: blue
}
#center {
  fill: #00cc00;
}
#top {
  fill: #cc3333;
}
#right {
  fill: #663399;
}
#left {
  fill: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <g id="buttons">
    <rect id="center" x="25" y="25" height="50" width="50" />
    <polygon id="top" points="0,0 100,0 75,25 25,25" />
    <polygon id="right" points="100,0 75,25 75,75 100,100" />
    <polygon id="bottom" points="0,100 25,75 75,75 100,100" />
    <polygon id="left" points="0,0 25,25 25,75 0,100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Note:** As each of the elements inside the SVG has an ID, you should be able to target them with JS/Jquery.

Comment: Nice answer. Any specific advantages of `display: block` for `svg` or is it only for the margin to work? I have not seen it used elsewhere and just to trying to understand if there is any benefit.

Comment: No that was just for the margin

Answer (score 12):

The old version is below, it resizes using jQuery. But after looking at this question: [SVG polygon points with percentage units support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498855/svg-polygon-points-with-percentage-units-support), you can achieve the same effect by applying percentages and without needing any JS:

```
<div id="svg-container">
    <svg id="mySVG" width='100%' height='100%' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style='background-color: whitesmoke'>
        <polygon id="ok" points="25,25 75,25 75,75 25,75" />
        <polygon id="up" points="0,0 100,0 75,25 25,25" />
        <polygon id="right" points="100,0 100,100 75,75 75,25" />
        <polygon id="down" points="0,100 25,75 75,75 100,100" />
        <polygon id="left" points="0,0 25,25 25,75 0,100" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/th4uo8wk/4/

---

Old answer:

Oops, by the time I had it ready, Paulie_D had come with the answer.

Well, here you have a responsive one (you can [see it working on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/th4uo8wk/3/), resize the screen to see it working responsively):

HTML:

```
<svg id="mySVG" height="20%" width="20%">
    <polygon id="ok" points="50,50 150,50 150,150 50,150" />
    <polygon id="up" points="0,0 200,0 150,50 50,50" />
    <polygon id="right" points="200,0 200,200 150,150 150,50" />
    <polygon id="down" points="0,200 50,150 150,150 200,200" />
    <polygon id="left" points="0,0 50,50 50,150 0,200" />
</svg>
```

JS/JQUERY

```
function resizeButtons() {
    // get the width
    var w = $("#mySVG").width();

    // make it squared
    $("#mySVG").height(w);

    // recalculate the position of each polygon
    $("#ok").attr("points", w * 0.25 + "," + w * 0.25 + " " + w * 0.75 + "," + w * 0.25 + " " + w * 0.75 + "," + w * 0.75 + " " + w * 0.25 + "," + w * 0.75);
    $("#up").attr("points", "0,0 " + w + ",0 " + w * 0.75 + "," + w * 0.25 + " " + w * 0.25 + "," + w * 0.25);
    $("#left").attr("points", w + ",0 " + w + "," + w + " " + w * 0.75 + "," + w * 0.75 + " " + w * 0.75 + "," + w * 0.25);
    $("#down").attr("points", "0," + w + " " + w * 0.25 + "," + w * 0.75 + " " + w * 0.75 + "," + w * 0.75 + " " + w + "," + w);
    $("#right").attr("points", "0,0 " + w * 0.25 + "," + w * 0.25 + " " + w * 0.25 + "," + w * 0.75 + " 0," + w);
}
```

CSS

```
svg { background:#ccc; }
#ok { fill: red; }
#up { fill: blue; }
#down { fill: green; }
#right { fill: yellow; }
#left { fill: orange; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the same idea about making it responsive. SVG really is the better option in this case.

Comment: If you just use a % width on the SVG it's automatically responsive. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/5a603f8cdb764f01c87e2086714a2d25?editors=110 Not sure you need any JS/JQ.

Comment: @Paulie_D, right. I saw this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498855/svg-polygon-points-with-percentage-units-support and updated the code. There's no need for JS to resize

Answer (score 9):

As others have already pointed out, you should use SVG for this. Below is a CSS alternative that you may use.

It uses transformed pseudo-elements and `transform-origin` property. To make it responsive, you need to change the units. As the units are in em in this approach, simply change the font size in the parent, or the body element.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gc9dsk0h/)**

```css
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.left, .right, .top, .bottom, .ok {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    position: relative;
}
.left {
    background-color: #FFBF00;
    margin-top: 10em;
}
.right {
    background-color: #FF7E00;
    margin-top: -10em;
    margin-left: 20em;
}
.top {
    background-color: #D3212D;
    margin-top: -20em;
    margin-left: 10em;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: #318CE7;
    margin-top: 10em;
    margin-left: 10em;
}
.ok {
    background-color: #3B444B;
    margin-top: -21.666em;
    margin-left: 8.333em;
    height: 13.33em;
    width: 13.33em;
}
.ok span {
    line-height: 6.666em;
    text-align: center;
    width: inherit;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.left:before, .left:after, .right:before, .right:after, .top:before, .top:after, .bottom:before, .bottom:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.left:before, .right:before {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(45deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(45deg);
    transform: skewY(45deg);
}
.top:before, .bottom:before {
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(45deg);
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.left:after, .right:after {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-45deg);
    transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
.top:after, .bottom:after {
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.left:before, .left:after, .bottom:before, .bottom:after {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
.right:before, .right:after, .top:before, .top:after {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
/*HOVER STYLES*/
.top:hover, .right:hover, .bottom:hover, .left:hover, .ok:hover {background: #F7E7CE; transition: 0.3s ease;}
.ok:hover span {color: #222;}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="ok"><span>OK</span></div>
```

**Screenshot (gif)**

[image]

---

**Browser support:** IE 9+, GC 4+, FF 3.5+, Safari 3.1+, Opera 11.5+