# Creating geometrical shapes with handle for click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

My requirement is to create clickable areas with geometrical shapes inside a square div.

[image]

Here on this square div when user clicks on the triangle part the color should change to yellow. Similarly the color should change on selecting the other 2 areas.
I tried using CSS3 but failed. Please help me in this.

Fiddle demo is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/fh0vbahh/).

```
<div class="square">
  <div class="trapeziumRt"></div>
  <div class="trapeziumLt"></div>
</div>


.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
.trapeziumRt {
    border-bottom: 43px solid green;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    right: -28px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.trapeziumLt {
    border-bottom: 43px solid #C6C76F;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0;  
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-89deg);
}
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: and where is your code effort ?

Comment: This is an ideal place for an SVG. something like this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835743/using-css-and-html5-to-create-navigation-buttons-using-trapezoids/28836769#28836769

Comment: Or maybe you should use a map.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is the best choice for creating such shapes and adding events. The shape given in question can be created by using a combination of three `path` elements (one for the triangle, two for the trapezium on either sides).

SVG `path` elements create the required shape by drawing lines connecting the coordinates provided in the `d` attribute. For example, here the triangle is formed by drawing line from (1,99) to (50,60), then from (50,60) to (99,99) and finally closing the path by drawing a line from (99,99) to (1,99).

Once the required shapes are created, click event handlers are attached using JavaScript and when they are clicked, the `yellow` class (which sets the `fill` to `yellow`) is toggled on or off.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('path');
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('yellow');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
path {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: black;
  fill: transparent;
}
.yellow {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox='0 0 100 100'>
  <path id='triangle' d='M1,99 50,60 99,99z' pointer-events="visible" />
  <path id='trapezium-1' d='M1,1 50,1 50,60 1,99z' pointer-events="visible" />
  <path id='trapezium-1' d='M50,1 50,60 99,99 99,1z' pointer-events="visible" />
</svg>
```

---

Saying SVG is the best for this does not mean that it cannot be done with CSS(3). Below is a sample snippet for the same using CSS. Here the trapezoids are created by using `skewY` transforms on two child elements. The click event handler and its working is the same as applicable for the SVG snippet.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var els = document.querySelector('.square,.inner-element-1,.inner-element-2');
  els.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('yellow');
  });
}
```

```css
.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner-element-1,
.inner-element-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: calc(50% - 1px);
  height: calc(100% - 1px);
  border: 2px solid;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.inner-element-1 {
  left: -2px;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.inner-element-2 {
  right: -2px;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='square'>
  <div class='inner-element-1'></div>
  <div class='inner-element-2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! both css3 and svg were new to me. Thanks a lot Harry to show me the possibilities. Actually 1 of the comment asking me to try SVG did the job. But using CSS3  it was a hard task. Thanks once again Harry.