# Use of viewBox inside CSS SVG inline code creates repeating image, how to prevent repeating?

Tags: css, svg

I have HTML code:

```
<div class="special-cell">TEST</div>
```

and CSS code:

```
.special-cell {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><rect x='0%' y='0%' width='25%' height='33%' stroke='yellow' fill='yellow' stroke-width='1'/></svg>");
}
```

Fiddle code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tomrhodes/7vtw3yhg/

I need to fill the background of my `div` with shapes, the aspect ratio and the size of my `div` can be arbitrary and that is why I am using percentages in my rect. Of course, repeating should not appear, only one rectangle should be inside `div`. If I remove `viewBox`, then `svg` is working as expected - no repeating. But I am required to draw polygon inside `div` as well and polygon does not allow to specigy poins in percentages, that is why I am required (according to [SVG polygon points with percentage units support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498855/svg-polygon-points-with-percentage-units-support)) use `viewBox` but it creates repeating pattern if the width of my `div` is larger than height.

How to prevent repeating of svg if viewBox is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the SVG to stretch the full width of the background, add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to your SVG:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7vtw3yhg/17/

```css
.special-cell {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'><rect x='0%' y='0%' width='25%' height='33%' stroke='yellow' fill='yellow' stroke-width='1'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="special-cell">TEST</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly I am trying to prevent - svg picture contains one yellow rectangle at the left-upper corner, but there are lot of yellow rectangles now, unneeded repeating. I am trying to arrive at the result that can be achieved by removing viewBox: one rectangle that takes 25%*33% of horizontal gray area. Unfortunately I should accommodate viewBox somehow because I will need to add polygons and they are not supporting percentage values and I would like to create sizeable code.

Comment: There is only one yellow rectangle in my example.  If that's not what you want, then I don't understand what you want.  Maybe add a mockup image to your question so we can see what you are after.

Comment: Ok, I checked now from mobile and mobile Firefox shows multiple rectangles, but mobile Chrome shows exactly as expected - one rectangle in the right position and size. I guess, that desktop browser behave similarly, I am mostly using Firefox and apparently somethinhg wrong is with it.

Comment: If it is rendering wrong in Firefox, I encourage you to [report the bug to them](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Glad it is working how you want.  With your `viewBox` of 100x100, your coordinates are already in percentages.  So setting `x="59"` is equivalent to to setting it to 59%.

Comment: When I added "background-size: 100% 100%;", then code started to work in Firefox as well, so there is no Firefox bug. Code does not work in Microsoft Edge, but who cares about it.., I guess there is wider problem with SVG in Edge and anyway, we are not goind to support Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/7vtw3yhg/8/

You need to use following styles to avoid repeating of background image

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: It removes repeating indeed, but it would be better that rectangle (that is defined inside svg) took full  25% from horizontal area, but clearly it takes a lot smaller area now..

Comment: Updated fiddle at "https://jsfiddle.net/7vtw3yhg/12/". use background-size:cover.

Comment: Thanks, but now yellow rectangle has 100% height, but it should have only 33% height and be at the left right corder (take 25%*33% area). I feel that something should be changed inside svg picture specifically.