# How to tame SVGs as background-images

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following goal: I wanted to place a heart within a container -  scaled and positioned.

First I wanted to use an icon font but I've discarded the idea. Second option to load the heart as an image I've discarded too - I have to use the heart a few times on my recent project and I wanted to save http requests. Therefore I wanted to go with the SVG as a background-image option. But the problem is, somehow I am unable to tame that beast. I've built a sample pen to illustrate the issues and parts I don't understand.

The un-base64-encoded optimized SVG looks like that:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960 960"><polygon points="756,168.4 593.5,168.4 480,258.3 366.5,168.4 204,168.4 30,349 480,791.6 930,349"/></svg>
```

The sample code you can find [from my codepen.](http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/kAone)

Basically I have three related questions (normally I prefer to post separate issues but those three questions are basically way too connected therefore I hope it's ok):

1. The sizing: .heart1 has a width and height of 100% and everything displays fine. If you use suiting px values all is fine too but if you try to enter ems the heart isn't shown anymore. Why?
2. The green box: .heart1 has a width of 100% but if you drag the browser window bigger the heart only grows to some point and then only the green box keeps on growing. I thought SVGs are more or less able to scale to "infinity"?
3. The yellow box: My basic goal was to make the heart a bit smaller than the width of the yellow box, center it horizontally within and give the heart some top margin. Width and height of .heart2 are set to 75%. But somehow I am unable to position the heart within the box neither with top, left and/or right properties nor in background:url with "no-repeat center 2em" e.g. . It just doesn't react.

Comment: This looks like 3 different questions.

Comment: Pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919076/how-to-make-a-svg-element-expand-or-contract-to-its-parent-container , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515524/how-do-i-scale-an-svg-polygon-in-ems

Answer (score 0):

I use a block of code shown below to fit svg in a DIV. It works best in a DIV with the same width/height. As you can see below it uses **getBBox()** to change its **viewBox**, plus changes the svg width/height values.
It works cross browser: IE10+/CH31/FF23

```
var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
var bbw=bb.width
var bbh=bb.height

//--use greater of bbw vs bbh--
if(bbw>=bbh)
    var factor=bbw/divWH
else
    var factor=bbh/divWH

var vbWH=divWH*factor

var vbX=(bbw-vbWH)/2
var vbY=(bbh-vbWH)/2
//---IE/CH---
if(!isFF)
{
    var ViewBox=mySVG.viewBox.baseVal
    ViewBox.x=vbX
    ViewBox.y=vbY
    ViewBox.width=vbWH
    ViewBox.height=vbWH
}
else
    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",vbX+" "+vbY+" "+vbW+" "+vbH)

//--requred for FF/CH---
if(!isIE)
{
    mySVG.setAttribute("width","100%")
    mySVG.setAttribute("height","100%")
}
else
{
    mySVG.removeAttribute("width")
    mySVG.removeAttribute("height")
}
```

The svg is centered both left/right and top/bottom within the DIV, plus maintains its aspect ratio. This should help get you started.