# I want to increase the width of the breadcrumbs of polygon on sequence sunburst chart on d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My chart is based on the example :

https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426

I want to resize the breadcrumb polygon size so as to increase the width. Here is what I changed from the original-

```
entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .attr("width",500)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I have also attached the screnshot.
PS: I added a width attribute but it didn't work out. Please help.
[I have attached the image showing the need for increasing the width of the breadcrumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DLtV.png)

Comment: I don't think it is the width of the polygon you need. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515524/how-do-i-scale-an-svg-polygon-in-ems

Comment: @mkaran Sorry I am very new to d3js so i need a code in javascript for increasing the width of the polygon so that the numerical data fits in it which is currently exceeding the limit as you can see in the image I had attached.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from the example you have provided, you need to modify `breadcrumbPoints` function, so that the breadcrumb width is not fixed but the length of the (string I assume) name:

```
// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  var bcLen = d.name.length + 10; // name here should be string else d.name.toString().length
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(bcLen + ",0"); // instead of b.w which is fixed
  points.push(bcLen + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2)); // same
  points.push(bcLen + "," + b.h); // same
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}
```

I haven't tried this but it seems pretty logical to me, so, give it a go and let me know if it works :)

Good luck!

Edit: Come to think about it, you should also change `x` in text accordingly:

```
entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d){ return (d.name.length + 10 + b.t) / 2})
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

And:

```
// Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (d.name.length + 10 + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually i found the solution I had to change the w value in the following code                                                                
        var b = {
  w: 200, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
}; It worked :)